# In Java why would one want to put the brackets in front of the name of an aray?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been told that

```
int[] numbers
```

and

```
int numbers[]
```

are equivalent. I've only ever seen the former though. What impetus is there, if ever, to write the latter?

Comment: Don't know Java, but if they really are the same, as you've stated, then it's preference and arguments for either are moot, similar to having `++i;` or `i++;` when they're on their own lines by themselves...

Comment: After much consideration, i agree.

Comment: Note `int numbers[], letters;` is different from `int[] numbers, letters;`. (Declaring two variables in the same declaration is a bad idea anyway.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesnt really matter, but, my personal preference is for `int[] numbers` as it more logically follows the `class instance_name` pattern.

After all you are really delcaring an "array of integers" called "numbers", the second form is slightly misleading as its more of declaring "an integer" called "numbers" oh and by the way its actually an array of "numbers".

Answer (score 7):

None.  It's just a legacy from C syntax.  However, it should be noted that C and Java arrays are very different.  Java arrays are more like a malloc-allocated pointer with a length field.

Answer (score 1):

just becoz of- the way earlier we used to declare in C. 
two options are available...chose as per ur convenience. No big deal, java provided new way of declaring array & remained the old way of declaring array also. Full freedom for programmer....cool stuff. no confusion at all.